# SSL certificate verifaction error cPanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel

When I want to install my certificates on cPanel, I see this error:

> error Certificate verification failed!
>   
> Executed /usr/bin/openssl verify -CApath /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles:
>   
> stdin: CN = example.com
>   
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by including the CA trusted bundle at the bottom.